# Printing an invisible NSView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, printing, nsview

Initially I created a simple program with a custom NSView.  I drew a picture (certificate) and printed it!  beautiful!  Everything worked great!

I then moved my custom NSView to an existing application.  My hope was that when a user hit print it would print this certificate.  Simple enough.  I figured a could have a NSView pointer in my controller code.  Then at initialization I would populate the pointer.  Then when someone wanted to print the certificate it would print.  The problem is that all of my drawing code is in the "drawRect" method.  This method doesn't get called because this view is never displayed in a window.

I have heard that others use non-visible NSView objects just for printing.  What do I need to do?  I really don't want to show this view to the screen.

Rodger

Answer (score 2):

**You don't have to create the view in advance, you can create it when needed.**

If you have Document Based application and a view that you want to dump to printer, then in our `MyDocument` (or whatever you call it) that extends `NSDocument` you would implement:

```
- (NSPrintOperation *)printOperationWithSettings:(NSDictionary *)ps
                                           error:(NSError **)e
```

The view then uses standard `drawRect:` for drawing.

Example, here `PeopleView` just draws a `table` of people details, it takes a `NSDictonary` of people `employees` here:

```
- (NSPrintOperation *)printOperationWithSettings:(NSDictionary *)ps
                                           error:(NSError **)e
{
    PeopleView * view = [[PeopleView alloc] initWithPeople:employees];
    NSPrintInfo * printInfo = [self printInfo];
    NSPrintOperation * printOp
        = [NSPrintOperation printOperationWithView:view
                                         printInfo:printInfo];
    [view release];
    return printOp;
}
```

You can look for more details in chapter 27, Printing, in Hillegass' Cocoa Programming For Mac OS X.

Comment: Don't you have to set the frame of the view? Or does the print op do that for you?

Comment: No, this is all you have to do if you have view that can draw itself. I created the example and it works. I'm using the data in different ways and when I want to print them I use the `PeopleView`.